# Variable has already been used before and assigned a value

Tags: vb.net

I' am making a bot for my assignment which uses proxy to browse websites. I have field called "Browse" which lets me browse for the proxy file and reads into an array and shows the total number of proxy from the counter. I' am stuck here in the following. The following are the code that am currently using. Please help

> Variable proxyArray has already been used before and assigned a value. A null
>   reference exception could result at runtime.

**Code**

```
Private Sub browserProxy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles browserProxy.Click
        Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing
        Dim selectedFile As String
        Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
        Dim proxyArray() As String
        Dim totalProxy As Integer

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt"
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = False

        If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            selectedFile = String.Format(openFileDialog1.FileName)
            Dim objreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(selectedFile)
            i = 0
            Do While Not objreader.EndOfStream
                proxyArray(i) = objreader.ReadLine
                i += 1
            Loop
            totalProxy = i
            objreader.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

**This pops up during runtime.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is right, you have declared the variable `proxyArray` but you never initialize it. This is an initialized array with 10 strings that are `Nothing`
:

```
Dim proxyArray(9) As String
```

But since the number of items is unknown you should use a `List(Of String)` anyway. It is resizable whereas an array has a fixed size.

```
Dim proxList As New List(Of String)
'...'
     proxList.Add(objreader.ReadLine)
```

If you need an array you can use `proxList.ToArray()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a `List(Of String)`, or `ReDim Preserve proxyArray(i + 1)` each time.